# The problem is ngfor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

I was trying to consume an api to angular but gettting stuck. Would you like to help me out ? The code as follows.

Other

HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of contact">
    <h1>  {{data.ConDepartment}} </h1>
    <h1>  </h1>
</div>
```

service:

```
 getContact(){

  //  return this.http.get('https://localhost:44310/api/contacts/getcontact');
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44310/api/contacts/getcontact').map(res => res );
}
```

TS:

```
contact:{}
//  user:{}


  constructor(private service:ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.service. getContact().subscribe(res=>{
    this.contact=res;

//   this.service.getUsers().subscribe(res=>{
// this.user=res;


console.log(res);
   }  );
```

JSON:

```
//localhost:44310/api/contacts/getcontact

{
  "ConId": 1,
  "ConCcrId": null,
  "ConCtrId": null,
  "ConForename": "SUPER",
  "ConSurname": "USER",
  "ConDepartment": null,
  "ConDivision": null,
  "ConJobtitle": "SUPER_USER",
  "ConGender": " ",
}
```

I want to display the json data in html. Please let me know if you help me out. Also, I was trying another fake API and it was working.

Comment: Because your endpoint(api) returns back object not an array of object, you can't use ngFor, just do `{{contact.ConDepartment}}` on your HTML.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you so much. It solved.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the response from the API is an object, not an array. If you are trying to iterate through the properties of the array on the `*ngFor` and display it on your view, you can use the [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe instead.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of contact | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}: {{item.value}}
</div>
```